# like pattern '[0-9][0-9][0-1][0-9]'

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a `nvarchar` field with 4 digits.
The first 2 digits are between 00 and 99.
The next 2 digits should be a number between 00 and 15

My SQl `like` looks like this:

```
I4020 like '[0-9][0-9][0-1][0-9]'
```

The problem is that e.g. 1219 is possible.

Is it possible to do this with the like pattern?

BR Stefan

Answer (score 5):

It's not possible to do this with *one* LIKE pattern. However, you can use two of them:

```
(I4020 like '[0-9][0-9]0[0-9]' OR I4020 like '[0-9][0-9]1[0-5]')
```

Alternatively, if the field always contains digits, you can use numerical matching:

```
I4020 LIKE '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
AND CONVERT(int, RIGHT(I4020, 2)) <= 15
```

Note, though, that T-SQL `AND` does not short-circuit: The latter query might fail if the two rightmost letters of `I4020` are not numeric.

Comment: you can also use the `|` operator can’t you?

Comment: @skp: A [LIKE pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx) is not a regular expression. It only supports a very limited set of operators.

Comment: you’re right. Then IS SIMILAR, or SIMILAR, I don’t remember well

Comment: You could always create a CLR function to allow a regex match - of course this goes beyond standard T-SQL

Comment: I don't think MSSQL supports SIMILAR

Answer (score 2):

Brake intervals

```
(I4020 like '[0-9][0-9]0[0-9]' OR I4020 like '[0-9][0-9]1[0-5]')
```

Answer (score 0):

`(I4020 like '[0-9][0-9]0[0-9]' OR I4020 like '[0-9][0-9]1[0-5]')`